# Bash, issue on for loop

Tags: bash, for-loop, amazon-s3

I want to list specified files (files uploaded yesterday) from an amazon S3.
Then I want to loop on this list, and for every single element of the list I want to unzip the file.

My code is:

```
for file in s3cmd ls s3://my-bucket/`date +%Y%m%d -d "1 day ago"`*
do s3cmd get $file
arrIN=(${file//my-bucket\//})
gunzip ${arrIN[1]}
done
```

so basicaly arrIN=(${file//my-bucket//}); explodes my string and allow me to retrieve the name of the file I want to unzip.

Thing is, file are downloading but nothing is being unzip, so I tried:

```
for file in s3cmd ls s3://my-bucket/`date +%Y%m%d -d "1 day ago"`*
do s3cmd get $file
echo test1
done
```

Files are being downloaded but nothing is being echo. Loop is just working for the first line...

Comment: `$file` gets set to `s3smd`, then `ls`, then whatever the next expression evaluates to. That's probably not what you want.

Comment: Why are you using `ls` there, it seems superfluous.  Try `echo s3://my-bucket/$(date +%Y%m%d -d "1 day ago")*` to see what I mean.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use command substitution to iterate over the result of the desired `s3smd ls` command.

```
for file in $(s3cmd ls s3://my-bucket/$(date +%Y%m%d -d "1 day ago")*); do
```

However, this isn't the preferred way to iterate over the output of a command, since in theory the results could contain whitespace. See [Bash FAQ 001](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) for the proper method.